# Making the edges more bright and narrow using opencv

Tags: opencv, edge-detection

I have two images as follows. I need to convert first image into the second. I am using Opencv. What should I use?

[image]

[image]

Canny is giving the following response, so I don't think it will work. Any other suggestion.

[image]

Comment: an Edge filter, like Canny or Sobel

Comment: perhaps erode()/dilate() if needed after that

Comment: @berak I have applied Canny, but the outcome is not as expected.

Comment: Did you try different parameters for canny()?